# Calculation of average based on a weighted score

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate an average score based on a list of parameter scores (between 0 and 5). The trick is that I want to be able to weight each parameter. 
Eg:

```
        Parameter A     Parameter B     Parameter C
Weight  100%            70%             0%
Score   4               5               0
```

In the above example, the average score should be 3,75 as parameter c is left out.

I've tried with this formula: `=IF.ERROR(SUM((A3*A5);(B3*B5);(C3*C5))/COUNTA(A3:C3);"")`. The formula seems to work if none of the parameters weight is equal to 0. How can I adjust the formula, so it excludes a score if weight is equal to zero?

I think it should be rather easy, I just can't get it to work.

Comment: It's unclear to me what's your definition of average score. Why do you think that *"the average score should be 3,75"*? Shouldn't it be (4*1 + 5*.7 + 0*0)/(1+0.7+0) = 4.42?

Comment: (4*1 + 5*0.7) / 2 = 3,75 :-)

Comment: Then I'll undelete my answer, but it doesn't seem the right way to calculate a weighted mean to me ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `COUNTA` you are counting the non empty cells, while you should count the non zero cells. So, assuming that the weights are in `A3:C3` and the scores in `A5:C5`:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(A3:C3;A5*C5)/COUNTIF(A3:C3;">0");"Error: all the weigths are 0")
```

Comment: Thanks - that was indeed my issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

=SUMPRODUCT( A2:A4, B2:B4 ) / SUM( B2:B4 )

Source : https://exceljet.net/formula/weighted-average

Comment: Yeah, except this does not allow some of my scores/weights to be zero. I need a formula that takes that into account.

Comment: It will be helpful, Please go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222679/how-to-calculate-weighted-average-for-0-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Or you can use IFERROR to suppress the #DIV/0! error. For eg. =IFERROR(A1/A3,0)

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

```
(1*4 + 0.7*5) / 2 = 3.75
```

In other world the formula is:

```
((WeightA/100 * scoreA) + (WeightB/100 * scoreB) + (WeightC/100 * scoreC)) / 3
```

Comment: Yes, but I need a formula that works no matter what parameter weight is changed. That will differ from time to time.

Comment: This formula doesn't allow scores / weights to be zero either.

Comment: Yes it does. if weight is zero then it's 0/100 * score and if score is zero then it's weight/100  * 0, so the result is 0 nevertheless

Comment: You're right. Had to do with the counta formula I used for division. When using count if(A3:C3;"<>0") for division, It worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3;B1:B3) / COUNTIF(B1:B3;"<>0") / 100
```

Something like this would work

Comment: If you do the countif like this, then if any of my weights are equal to zero, it won't work. And the is my point. Some of the weights will be 0 and the corresponding score should just be ignored then.

Comment: Can you add more test cases then? It seems to work okay for the test case you provided. `(100*4+70*5+0*0) / 2 = 3.75` It doesn't ignore 0 weights explicitly but they're automatically ignored (multiply by 0).